# Laravel - How to eager load pivot relation to prevent N+1 query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-6, eloquent-relationship

I have four tables:

Orders:

```
1. id
2. number
```

OrderProduct:

```
1. order_id
2. product_id
3. unit_id
4. quantity
```

Products:

```
1. id
2. name
```

Units:

```
1. id
2. name
```

And I use `belongsToMany` to define the relation between `Order` and `Product`:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
            ->withPivot(
                'order_id',
                'product_id',
                'unit_id',
                'price',
                'quantity'
            )
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->using(OrderProduct::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class)
            ->withPivot(
                'order_id',
                'product_id',
                'unit_id',
                'price',
                'quantity'
            )
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->using(OrderProduct::class);
    }
}
```

and my pivot table ( OrderProduct ) is following:

```
class OrderProduct extends Pivot
{
    public function unit()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Unit::class, 'unit_id');
    }
}
```

and how do I eager load the `unit relation` in the `OrderProduct` to prevent N+1 query when I want to take the unit name like following:

```
@foreach($order->products as $product)
{{ $product->pivot->unit->name }}
@endforeach
```

I use Laravel 6.18.22 and PHP 7.4.7 on Nginx.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can but I found this https://github.com/ajcastro/eager-load-pivot-relations